# Change the location of Edit Profile

Tags: 7, users

I am using Profile 2.

When the user clicks the 'Edit My Profile' tab, I would like its destination to be:

```
/user/175/edit/about-you
```

Where about-you is a Profile2 type.

How do I change the path of the tabs?
I am also using TabTamer, but this module does not let you change the path, only the label and enable/disable the link.

EDIT
I have tried the below code in template.php with no results.(after changing the theme name)

```
function THEMENAME_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%/edit'] = $items['user/%/edit/about-you'];
  unset($items['user/%/edit']);
}
```

Comment: please see this https://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/drupal/drupal-7-8-alter-system-path-custom-paths-example. It might be of some help

Comment: Thanks Shreya Shetty, I have tired the code in the question edit above with no results. Could it be the use of the % for the UID?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by custom module.For this please use below code.First you need to create custom menu using hook_menu.

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function custom_menu() {
 $items['user/%/edit/about-you'] = array(
  'title' => 'About You',
  'page callback' => 'edit_about_you',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
 );
return $items;
}
```

Now You need to write page callback for this menu item.

```
function edit_about_you($uid){
  $profile = profile2_load_by_user($uid,'profile_type'); // or by default main
  $form_state = form_state_defaults();
  form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'profile2_page');
  return entity_ui_get_form('profile2', $profile, 'edit', $form_state);
}
```

This will return profile edit page for user.Now you need to redirect user when click Edit My Profile tab for this you can user hook_init for that. Check your path argument and redirect user to new created path.

Thanks